# I'm trying to do load testing using JMeter 5.5 . I have added cookie values for my request, but the values are not passing during the execution

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

I'm trying to do load testing using JMeter 5.5. I have added cookie values for my request, but the values are not passing during the execution.

Can someone help me on this.

[HTTP Cookie Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi3Me.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `standard` policy you're supposed to properly fill in "Domain" and "Path" fields and if there will be match in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler - the cookie will be sent.

In case you want to send cookies with all requests no matter what is the current domain and path - choose another policy, i.e. `netscape`

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)
- [Using HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265)